# Javascript in asp .Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm getting WebResource error in my asp.Net page:

```
var __pendingCallbacks = new Array();

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Array' is undefined
```

I have no idea what might cause this to happen.  Isn't Array part of Javascript itself?  Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
The problem is that this isn't code that I wrote, it's built into the page structure in asp.Net.

**EDIT**
The problem only occurs in IE9 and only when run in IE9 mode (not compatibility)

*Code:*
(This is dynamically generated code, sorry for the length.  Problem is about halfway down)

```
function WebForm_PostBackOptions(eventTarget, eventArgument, validation, validationGroup, actionUrl, trackFocus, clientSubmit) {
    this.eventTarget = eventTarget;
    this.eventArgument = eventArgument;
    this.validation = validation;
    this.validationGroup = validationGroup;
    this.actionUrl = actionUrl;
    this.trackFocus = trackFocus;
    this.clientSubmit = clientSubmit;
}
function WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(options) {
    var validationResult = true;
    if (options.validation) {
        if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
            validationResult = Page_ClientValidate(options.validationGroup);
        }
    }
    if (validationResult) {
        if ((typeof(options.actionUrl) != "undefined") && (options.actionUrl != null) && (options.actionUrl.length > 0)) {
            theForm.action = options.actionUrl;
        }
        if (options.trackFocus) {
            var lastFocus = theForm.elements["__LASTFOCUS"];
            if ((typeof(lastFocus) != "undefined") && (lastFocus != null)) {
                if (typeof(document.activeElement) == "undefined") {
                    lastFocus.value = options.eventTarget;
                }
                else {
                    var active = document.activeElement;
                    if ((typeof(active) != "undefined") && (active != null)) {
                        if ((typeof(active.id) != "undefined") && (active.id != null) && (active.id.length > 0)) {
                            lastFocus.value = active.id;
                        }
                        else if (typeof(active.name) != "undefined") {
                            lastFocus.value = active.name;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (options.clientSubmit) {
        __doPostBack(options.eventTarget, options.eventArgument);
    }
}
var __pendingCallbacks = new Array();
var __synchronousCallBackIndex = -1;
function WebForm_DoCallback(eventTarget, eventArgument, eventCallback, context, errorCallback, useAsync) {
    var postData = __theFormPostData +
                "__CALLBACKID=" + WebForm_EncodeCallback(eventTarget) +
                "&__CALLBACKPARAM=" + WebForm_EncodeCallback(eventArgument);
    if (theForm["__EVENTVALIDATION"]) {
        postData += "&__EVENTVALIDATION=" + WebForm_EncodeCallback(theForm["__EVENTVALIDATION"].value);
    }
    var xmlRequest,e;
    try {
        xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e) {
        try {
            xmlRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e) {
        }
    }
    var setRequestHeaderMethodExists = true;
    try {
        setRequestHeaderMethodExists = (xmlRequest && xmlRequest.setRequestHeader);
    }
    catch(e) {}
    var callback = new Object();
    callback.eventCallback = eventCallback;
    callback.context = context;
    callback.errorCallback = errorCallback;
    callback.async = useAsync;
    var callbackIndex = WebForm_FillFirstAvailableSlot(__pendingCallbacks, callback);
    if (!useAsync) {
        if (__synchronousCallBackIndex != -1) {
            __pendingCallbacks[__synchronousCallBackIndex] = null;
        }
        __synchronousCallBackIndex = callbackIndex;
    }
    if (setRequestHeaderMethodExists) {
        xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = WebForm_CallbackComplete;
        callback.xmlRequest = xmlRequest;
        xmlRequest.open("POST", theForm.action, true);
        xmlRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
        xmlRequest.send(postData);
        return;
    }
    callback.xmlRequest = new Object();
    var callbackFrameID = "__CALLBACKFRAME" + callbackIndex;
    var xmlRequestFrame = document.frames[callbackFrameID];
    if (!xmlRequestFrame) {
        xmlRequestFrame = document.createElement("IFRAME");
        xmlRequestFrame.width = "1";
        xmlRequestFrame.height = "1";
        xmlRequestFrame.frameBorder = "0";
        xmlRequestFrame.id = callbackFrameID;
        xmlRequestFrame.name = callbackFrameID;
        xmlRequestFrame.style.position = "absolute";
        xmlRequestFrame.style.top = "-100px"
        xmlRequestFrame.style.left = "-100px";
        try {
            if (callBackFrameUrl) {
                xmlRequestFrame.src = callBackFrameUrl;
            }
        }
        catch(e) {}
        document.body.appendChild(xmlRequestFrame);
    }
    var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
        xmlRequestFrame = document.frames[callbackFrameID];
        if (xmlRequestFrame && xmlRequestFrame.document) {
            window.clearInterval(interval);
            xmlRequestFrame.document.write("");
            xmlRequestFrame.document.close();
            xmlRequestFrame.document.write('<html><body><form method="post"><input type="hidden" name="__CALLBACKLOADSCRIPT" value="t"></form></body></html>');
            xmlRequestFrame.document.close();
            xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].action = theForm.action;
            var count = __theFormPostCollection.length;
            var element;
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                element = __theFormPostCollection[i];
                if (element) {
                    var fieldElement = xmlRequestFrame.document.createElement("INPUT");
                    fieldElement.type = "hidden";
                    fieldElement.name = element.name;
                    fieldElement.value = element.value;
                    xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].appendChild(fieldElement);
                }
            }
            var callbackIdFieldElement = xmlRequestFrame.document.createElement("INPUT");
            callbackIdFieldElement.type = "hidden";
            callbackIdFieldElement.name = "__CALLBACKID";
            callbackIdFieldElement.value = eventTarget;
            xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].appendChild(callbackIdFieldElement);
            var callbackParamFieldElement = xmlRequestFrame.document.createElement("INPUT");
            callbackParamFieldElement.type = "hidden";
            callbackParamFieldElement.name = "__CALLBACKPARAM";
            callbackParamFieldElement.value = eventArgument;
            xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].appendChild(callbackParamFieldElement);
            if (theForm["__EVENTVALIDATION"]) {
                var callbackValidationFieldElement = xmlRequestFrame.document.createElement("INPUT");
                callbackValidationFieldElement.type = "hidden";
                callbackValidationFieldElement.name = "__EVENTVALIDATION";
                callbackValidationFieldElement.value = theForm["__EVENTVALIDATION"].value;
                xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].appendChild(callbackValidationFieldElement);
            }
            var callbackIndexFieldElement = xmlRequestFrame.document.createElement("INPUT");
            callbackIndexFieldElement.type = "hidden";
            callbackIndexFieldElement.name = "__CALLBACKINDEX";
            callbackIndexFieldElement.value = callbackIndex;
            xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].appendChild(callbackIndexFieldElement);
            xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].submit();
        }
    }, 10);
}
```

Comment: try `__pendingCallbacks = []`

Comment: I didn't write the code.  See above ^^

Comment: are you running it in a browser? (which). Did some joker add `Array = undefined` to your code?

Comment: I don't think so, the code is generated by a MS library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because we have this setup

```
<collapsible panel>
    <iframe>
        <script>
        </script>
    </iframe>
</collapsible panel>
```

When the page loads, the panel being shown forces the script inside the iframe to be dragged through the DOM before the javascript libraries are loaded.  This seems to be a change in that was made for IE9.  I have yet to fine a way around this issue but at least I know the cause.  A temporary workaround is to force the compatibility of the page to IE8 using a meta tag in case anybody else runs into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed when I removed the SRC attribute from the iframe and I added onOpen event to jQuery's dialog:

```
open: function(){
    document.getElementById("iframename").src = "page.aspx";
}
```