# Runtime Error in Microsoft JScript: 'Array' is not defined

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, breakpoints

I'm using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

I have a hidden image button, that is set to visible="true" if the user uploads an image.
Here is the code:

**aspx file:**

```
           <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upOne" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnImageOne" runat="server" CssClass="btnImage" 
                        Visible="false" onclick="btnImageOne_Click" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDeleteOne" runat="server" CssClass="btnDelete" Visible="false"
                        onclick="btnDeleteOne_Click">&nbsp;</asp:LinkButton>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When visible, if clicked by the user, the button does:
**aspx.cs file:**

```
    protected void btnDeleteOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["fuOneFilename"] != null)
        {
            File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/animals/temp/") + (string)Session["fuOneFilename"]);
            Session["fuOneFilename"] = null;
            DisplayUploadedPictures();

            if (Session["mainImageFilename"] == Session["fuOneFilename"])
            {
                Session["mainImageFilename"] = null;
                DisplayMainImage();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

I placed a Break Point in the seccond line of the aspx.cs file.
After pressing F5, the application stops in a JavaScript line, located inside the jQuery *(unmodified)* file.

```
j = Array.prototype.push
```

I am presented with the message:

> Runtime Error in Microsoft JScript: 'Array' is not defined

In the same window, I can see three buttons:
Break, Continue, Ignore.

**Note:** Break Points in the Page Load run without a problem.

---

**The call stack says:**

> Anonymous Function  JScript
>
> JScript global code JScript

---

## Questions:

Q1. **Why is this happening?**

Q2. **How can I fix it?**

Comment: @SLaks, thank you for the interest. I added the call stack info on the original post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345057/javascript-in-asp-net seems like it might be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Q1. Why is this happening?

This error happens if you have the following configuration:

```
<collapsible panel>
    <iframe>
        <script>
        </script>
    </iframe>
</collapsible panel>
```

When the page loads, the panel being shown forces the script inside the iframe to be dragged through the DOM before the javascript libraries are loaded.

---

## Q2. How can I fix it?

The solution is to declare the source attribute through jQuery:

```
open: function(){
    document.getElementById("iframename").src = "page.aspx";
}
```

---

**Final Notes:**

All credits of this answer go to **spender**, who pointed me in the right direction with his comment.

However, I didnt want to leave this question "unanswered", so I decided to gather the info from [the linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345057/javascript-in-asp-net) and assemble it into a single post.